# Passing data between datagridview and textbox via two windows forms in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have `Form1 with`DataGridView` which consists of the following columns:

- ID
- NAME
- SHORT DESCRIPTION
- DESCRIPTION

Also I have a button that opens a separate `Form2` that has several textboxes.

How can I pass data from the second form to the original form, the value from textBox1 of Form2 will be passed to the ID column of the DataGridView?
It should be works same for all columns (textbox2 to NAME..textbox4 to DESCRIPTION)

```
    public class MyClassName
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string ShortDESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    }
}
```

// Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

public  MyClassName mc;
public Form2() 
{      
           InitializeComponent(); 
} // save text of your textboxs to your property public void.       
public void SaveTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass() 
{ 
     mc = new MyClassName();
     mc.ID = textBox1.Text; 
} 
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
} 
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

} 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SaveTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass();
    Close();
} 
}
}
```

\Form1

```
      public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Load+=new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClassName mc = new MyClassName();
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.ShowDialog();
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = mc;
    }

}
```

If you mean like this it doesn't pass the data.
Could you please correct me?

Comment: I'm on my phone now,but it seems you've got a black space between `ShowDialog` and `()`. Do you have it that way in your code or it was a copypaste mistake?

Comment: This is  only copypaste mistake. That's real code - f.ShowDialog();

Comment: Ok..then have a look at my answer and and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the code of `Form1` in the class. Move that to a method or event handler, as `Form_Load` or to the form constructor.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Load+=new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f= new Form2();
        f.ShowDialog();
        MyClass mc = f.mc;
    }

}
```

**Edit**
This is how your `Form2` should look like. Note `mc` is defined at class level,so it is accessible from outside the form:

```
MyClassName mc;
public Form2() 
{      
           InitializeComponent(); 
} // save text of your textboxs to your property public void.       
SaveTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass() 
{ 
     mc = new MyClassName();
     mc.ID = textBox1.Text; 
} 
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
} 
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

} 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SaveTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass();
    Close();
}
```

This would save your object on button click and close the form in that moment

Comment: At the string MyClass mc = f.mc; i still have got error - Error 1 "WindowsForm.Form2" does not contain a definition for "mc" and no extension method was found "mc", receiving type "WindowsForm.Form2" as the first argument (perhaps missing using directive or an assembly reference) C: \ Users \ berzh \ Desktop \ test_win_app \ WindowsForm \ WindowsForm \ Form1.cs 24 32 WindowsForm

Comment: Edit your question and paste your form1 and form2 code so i can see where is the problem. The error you've got now suggest that `mc` property is not accessible from outside Form2,maybe is it not public?

Comment: thanks for answer. it works but data doesn't passing. question was edited.

Comment: Hmm..now you talk about a gridview. You never mentioned it.

Comment: I know for sure  it was in question from start of this conversation

Comment: Please take a look at the beginning of question

Comment: Maybe,i don't remember. Anyway,you then need something like `this.dataGridView1.DataSource= mc` in your form1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have solved the problem.
You can help me if you want in following questions -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219745/how-i-can-update-and-delete-rows-in-datagridview

Comment: You're welcome,glad to help. Consider to mark the question as answered :)