# How I can update and delete rows in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How I can update (via my popup)?

//MyClass

```
public partial class Orders : Form
{
    BindingList<MyClass> blist = new BindingList<MyClass>();

    public Orders()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Add_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddOrder addO = new AddOrder();
        addO.ShowDialog();
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = blist;
        blist.Add(addO.mc);
        addO.Close();

    }



    private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

         {
                 if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count>0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
        }
                 else
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("Please select one row");
                   }

         }

    private void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {

            DataGridViewRow currRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            EditOrder eddO = new EditOrder(currRow);
            eddO.ShowDialog();
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(currRow.Index);
            blist.Add(eddO.mc);
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = blist;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select one row");
        }
    }


 }
```

//AddPopup

```
public partial class AddOrder : Form
{

    public MyClass mc;
    public AddOrder()
    {
        mc = new MyClass();
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
    public void SaveTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass()
    {

        mc.ID = txtID.Text;
        mc.Name = txtName.Text;
        mc.Desciption = txtDescription.Text;
        mc.DoctorID = txtDoctorID.Text;
        mc.DoctorName = txtDoctorName.Text;
    }

    private void AddOrder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass();
        Close();
    }


}
```

//Edit popup

```
public partial class EditOrder : Form
{
    public MyClass mc;
    public EditOrder()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public EditOrder(DataGridViewRow row)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        txtID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtDescription.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtDoctorID.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtDoctorName.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    }
    public void EditTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass()
    {

        mc = new MyClass();
        mc.ID = txtID.Text;
        mc.Name = txtName.Text;
        mc.Desciption = txtDescription.Text;
        mc.DoctorID = txtDoctorID.Text;
        mc.DoctorName = txtDoctorName.Text;
    }





    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass();
        Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditTextBoxesToMyObjectOfClass();
        Close();
    }

    private void EditOrder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

Some additional info. I realised edit function via remove and add row, any suggestions how to update it?(not just delete and enter new one)
One more question- if i press add button on main form and press cancel button on popup window, new row on main form created. How I can avoid it?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you clearing the columns = 0 and creating a new empty list when you try to add an item?  Your grid's datasource will always only have one item the way you are doing it.

Comment: that was bad copypaste. now it normal code in description.thanks for your attention.

Comment: You are still making a new list every time.  Create the list once, right under the line where you create the DataTable (and apparently don't use).  Set the grid's DataSource to that list (remove the AsEnumerable) in your constructor.

Comment: thanks, but how can I add second...N row after added first?

Comment: Use a BindingList instead of a List.  It's in the System.ComponentModel namespace.  Set the grid's DataSource in your form's constructor.

Comment: Great it works! 
I also have solved problem with delete. records. One more question left with edit created records. 
Could you please suggest smth?

Comment: You have your MC objects in your list, so try passing the highlighted one to your editor form.

Comment: I updated code. Could you please help me what i should do for correctly update created records?

Comment: You only set the DataSource once.  For the third time, move that line to your form's constructor.  When you edit a record, does it make sense to "add" it to the list?  No.  So don't.  You have to pass that object to your form, update the controls with the values, and save any changes back to your reference.  When you delete a row, you have to delete it from the list, not from the grid, since the grid is using a DataSource.  Some research on your part is required here.

Comment: Remove items from blist.  Then set the datasource to null and back to source to force paint to update the control. this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null; this.dataGridView1.DataSource = blist;

Comment: jdweng, but in this way when I select row in main form and press edit, all data will move to the edit popup?

Comment: LarsTech, >>You have to pass that object to your form, update the controls with the values, and save any changes back to your reference. Sounds easy and clear but couldn't realise it(